# Can you remove the 'apt' command to prevent users installing what they want?

Tags: apt, security

I would like to remove 'apt' from ubuntu.  I do not simply want to remove the repos, but the actual executable itself.

I know removing all the repos would cause apt to fail (be useless), but I want to make it so that someone couldn't simply add a repo and install what thy wanted.

Comment: IMO if you do it for "someone" then you can't perform that operations too. Adding a repository and installing something need root privileges. You can take `sudo` privileges instead.

Comment: You should make a non-admin user for that someone. Removing apt is a bad idea. Regular users can't install packages from repositories, and can't add/remove/edit repositories.

Comment: Removing apt just makes things a bit harder. People with root privs and network access, can reinstate the apt subsystem and its repository cache. And people without either cannot do anything. Would that be for a Docker image by any chance?

Comment: That "duplicate" is not a duplicate at all, this one is wanting to prevent people from running apt, the other is about whether it is possible for apt to remove itself.  Totally different response needed.

Comment: @thomasrutter I agree with the sentiment, but the second sentence clearly states the OP wants to remove Apt.

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be the old "don't do this, it's a bad idea and here's why" answer.

It is better to achieve what you want to do with the permissions built into the OS.

- Nobody that you don't fully trust to administer the system should have root or unrestricted sudo access.
- Give people permissions that allow them to do what they need to do, but restrict them from doing what you don't want them to do.

Doing what you want to do is a bad idea because:

- It is easy to circumvent.  If a user has root or sudo, they can install anything.  They can even simply re-install APT.  It is possible to manually install software on a system; DPKG and APT are not the only way to install software and are simply provided for convenience in managing what is installed.
- It leaves you unable to receive security updates to your software, leaving your system potentially open to intrusion and attacks.
- APT is merely a layer on top of the package manager, DPKG.  APT handles fetching of packages from repositories and keeping track of what is available in the repositories.  DPKG handles installing and configuring the packages and keeping track of which packages are installed.  If you remove APT, you can still install packages with DPKG by manually downloading the packages.  If you remove both, as discussed above you can install software manually the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a helpful command will be `dpkg --purge apt`

edited: after waltinator comment (thanks for taking time to post)

While indeed that's the command that will let you achieve the exact result you are asking for I'd really suggest to do a better thinking about removing a packet manager completely and instead try to achieve the same user experience or result through a tweak of the permissions (i.e. a user without root priviledges cannot install packages so maybe this use-case could be a smoother one for you).

Comment: That's how O. P. could do it, but it doesn't accomplish what he thinks it would, and is a Dumb Idea. Don't help him shoot himself in the foot.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think it's indeed a good point to add some explanation. Will edit to point out that it's not that useful and I'm not at all recommending, but I'm more for providing anyway the requested information.